# ¿Cómo escribir de derecha a izquierda?

Tags: javascript

A lo que me refiero es que como en el japonés o en el árabe, estos inician según yo de la parte superior derecha de la hoja. Y estaba interesado en saber si se podría hacer algo parecido con nuestro idioma. Es para un proyecto

No que simplemente se invierta el texto, si no que se pueda apreciar que se ordena desde el inicio de derecha a izquierda

Comment: Hola Padrón, bienvenido a [es.so]. Tu pregunta es un poco pobre porque necesitas añadir lo que has intentado y los problemas exactos. Has investigado algo en Google?  Pon, además, un ejemplo de HTML donde se reproduzca lo que intentas hacer, asi quien te responda puede poner su codigo y ver como está funcionando. Mira más info en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deberías añadir a tu pregunta los intentos que has realizado... de todas formas, y tal y como dice @jorge-bowen, debes añadir la propiedad CSS direction:rtl a tu input. Sin embargo con eso no conseguirás que las palabras y las letras también se ordenen de derecha a izquierda.

Para hacer eso tienes dos opciones (una deseable y sencilla y otra que dejo como orientativa):

- Utilizar la propiedad CSS `unicode-bidi: bidi-override`:

Es la más sencilla. Con esta propiedad se modifica el flujo de los caracteres en función de la `direction` indicada. En [este](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_unicode-bidi.asp) enlace tienes más info y en [este](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-unicode-bidi) más

```css
.reves{ 
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<input class="reves" type="text"/>
```

- Añadir JS (menos recomendable y habría que darle una vuelta):

Con este código al pulsar cualquier tecla distinta al <kbd>Supr</kbd> y <kbd>Delete</kbd> se añade al `value` del `input` el carácter [RLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) (Right-to-left-mark) con lo que la siguiente vez que se escriba el cursor estará a la izquierda del input.

```js
function rtl(e,elt) {
    if(e.keyCode != 46 && e.keyCode != 8)
    {
        elt.value += "\u200F";
    }
    else
    {
        elt.value = elt.value.substring(0, elt.value.length - 1);
    }
}
```

```css
.reves{ 
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<input class="reves" type="text" onkeyup="rtl(event,this)"/>
```

**Extra bonus**

Añado aquí la respuesta a tu pregunta del comentario. En el caso de la solución CSS, aunque el input se muestre de derecha a izquierda el valor almacenado en `value` sigue estando de izquierda a derecha. Para darle la vuelta puedes hacer uso de los `prototypes` de `Arrays` [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reverse) y [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join).

```
let stringInvertido = document.getElementById("miInput").value.split('').reverse().join('')
```

Obtenemos el valor del input, los troceamos por el caracter vacío (esto nos devolverá un `array` con una letra en cada posición, a continuación le damos la vuelta a las posiciones con `reverse` y luego unimos con `join` pasándole como parámetro el caracter vacío de nuevo.

```css
.reves{ 
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<input class="reves" id="miInput" type="text" onblur="console.log('Sin darle la vuelta: ' + this.value);console.log('Tras darle la vuelta: ' + this.value.split('').reverse().join(''));"/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias canijo, eres brillante. Pero otra cosa, ¿cómo hacer lo mismo con una cadena de texto? ósease que deposite un String en una variable

Comment: ¿Te refieres "a darle la vuelta" a una cadena existente o a guardar la cadena escrita en el input en una variable?

Comment: Guardarlo en una variable

Comment: Actualizo la respuesta con lo que pides. Si te parece la respuesta adecuada no dudes en aceptarla como correcta :)

Comment: Ok, creo que entendí. Pero no detecta saltos de línea ósease “\n” ni los Tabs estoy haciendo cosas locas XD XD

Comment: Y el primero estaba bien, básicamente estoy haciendo un idioma :v

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo directamente con CSS utilizando con las propiedades **direction** y **unicode-bidi**

```
body {
 direction: rtl; 
 unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

Comment: Wow, menuda propiedad lo del unicode

Answer (score 0):

Hola hay una propiedad CSS para esos casos por defecto se ordena en un campo input de izquierda a derecha `ltr` para tu caso seria de derecha a izquierda `rtl`, agrega esta propiedad css `direction: rtl`;

```html
<textarea style='width:100%;height:100px'>
  Este texto va de izquierda a derecha
</textarea>

<textarea style="direction:rtl;width:100%;height:100px;unicode-bidi: bidi-override">
  Este texto va de derecha a izquierda
</textarea>
```

Comment: añado a mi respuesta la propiedad que @cardeol ha indicado a su respuesta